# Subreport needs persistent legend text

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports XI and trying to create a text box that would be displayed on every page of my multi-paged subreport. The text box exists on either the left or right hand side of the resulting pages. Right now, I am only able to display the text box once and only because the text box is placed on the main report. I tried to place the text box on a possible "page" section of the subreport but was not able to find such section.

Appreciate whatever suggestions you have. Thank you all! Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

You can place a repeating text box in the page header or page footer section that will print on every page.

That is the most reliable way to guarantee it showing on each page. The real question is: What kind of information are you wanting to display? If it is dynamic information that changes with the data on each page, the solution is much more complicated. If you are showing a static item, like a disclaimer, then the solution provided should be sufficient.

If you need more specific help, please provide more information regarding type of content and what you have or haven't tried. This will keep people from wasting time on solutions you know don't work...

Answer (score 0):

Hi Create a formula @Group like below and apply group on this.And place the textbox on group header.

whilereadingrecords;
""

Goto change group->Repeat group header on each page.